# clojure core.typed error with assoc

Tags: clojure

So i have this bit of code

```
(defalias Tag 
  (U Keyword Integer))

(defalias Entity
  (HMap :mandatory {:type Tag} :complete? false))

(defn with-prop [entity :- Entity, prop :- Keyword, value :- Any] :- Entity
  (assoc entity prop value))
```

But it looks like with-prop is not properly typed, because core.typed says it should be:

```
(IPersistentMap Keyword Any)
```

While that is technically correct. i would like to preserve the Entity type because that guaranties the :type property is there.

is there anyway i can do that?

the only thing that interests me in this is case to have the :type property on there, it does not actually need to be a HMap, i guess it could be a IPersistentMap but i can't find a working way of adding a mandatory key to it.
(The examples on github wiki don't work for me)

I'm using version [org.clojure/core.typed "0.3.26"]

Thanks,

Boogie